# delphi..Onactive button disble confusion for a available form

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

hey im working on delphi 7,
and i have a scenario for a available form,
i have two forms

```
  1. FormOne 
  2. FormTwo
```

FormOne has a button

[image]

which create the FormTwo on button click

```
    var
     Form2:TForm2;
      begin
       Form2:=TForm2.Create(nil);
       Form2.ShowModal ;
        Form2.Free;
     end;
```

On **Form2** there is a button which i need to disable..(on some conditions)..
[image]

so on **activate** of **Form2** i did this

```
       if assigned(Form2) then
        begin
         Form2.Button1.Enabled:=False;
        end;
```

that is im checking if the form is created then disable the button..
since the code is in **Onactivate** meaning the form2 is already created according to [this](http://delphi.about.com/od/formsdialogs/a/delphiformlife.htm) the delphi form liyfe cyle is

> OnCreate -> OnShow -> OnActivate -> OnPaint -> OnResize -> OnPaint

..so the button1 should be disabled..but it **NOT** disabled.

[image]

Comment: Or 'Form2' is not assigned. Put a breakpoint on 'if assigned(..'.

Comment: with breakpoint - 'form2=nil'  y is it nil when it has been created?

Comment: because you haven't told 'unit2.Form2 := Form2' when you're creating your form in unit1.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz can you explain..i didnt get you

Comment: you're declaring a local 'Form2' variable in unit1, that's not the same variable with the 'Form2' in unit2, only their names are same. The 'Form2' in 'unit2', i.e. 'unit2.Form2' remains unassigned.

Comment: oh yes, i didnt notice that i had declared the local form2 variable and i was trying to see if its assigned or not..thanx for Serg and you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `Form2` is a local variable in your button click handler; in your `OnActivate` handler your are testing a global `Form2` variable from the unit where `TForm2` is defined; the second is not assigned if `TForm2` is not autocreated form.

Comment: yes..Got it your correct.. i removed the var Form2:TForm2; and directly created from the global variable Form2:TForm2; and it worked.!!